# using a postgres URL connection with an exclamation point in the password

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database using the URL format in a bash script:

```
psql "postgresql://larryq:password!@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

..however when I do so I get a message about a `!@localhost` event not found.

I've looked at the documentation but am not sure what's going on or how to escape the exclamation point.  I've tried single quoting around it, I've tried a backslash before it but nothing has worked.

Using the same format, but with a user without an exclamation point in their password, works great.  How can I pull it off with an exclamation in there?

Comment: Is it Bash, that throws the error or psql? In the former case you should add the Bash tag, so that the right people can find the question.

Comment: I'd store the password in a variable, then pass it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the password in `PGPASSWORD` and call `psql`:

```
edb=# create role foouser with password 'abc123!';
CREATE ROLE
edb=# alter user foouser with login;
ALTER ROLE
edb=> \q
[root@dba /]# PGPASSWORD='abc123!' psql "postgresql://foouser@localhost:5432/edb"
psql.bin (10.10.18)
Type "help" for help.

edb=>
```

or

```
[root@dba /]# PD='abc123!'
[root@dba /]# echo "postgresql://foouser:${PD}@localhost:5432/edb"
postgresql://foouser:abc123!@localhost:5432/edb
[root@dba /]# psql "postgresql://foouser:${PD}@localhost:5432/edb"
psql.bin (10.10.18)
Type "help" for help.

edb=>
```